# how to check if email already exist in firestore collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

***im trying to check if the user already exists in the collection and at this point i don't even know what to do. Please help me, here is my code so far.***

```
const Form = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState({});
  const [name, setName] = useState({});
 
  async function getEmail() {
    const emailUserQuery = query(
      collection(store, "emails"),
      where("email", "==", true ),
      limit(1)
    );
    // const querySnapshot = await getDocs(emailUserQuery);
    onSnapshot(emailUserQuery, (QuerySnapshot => {
      QuerySnapshot.forEach((snap) => {
        console.log(
        snap.id, "=>", snap.data()
        );
      });
    }))
   
  }
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: What determines if the user exists? emails are usually a bad choice as they can change. Additionally, you can use authentication to determine if the user has already signed up. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass the email address you're lookng for to the `where` clause:

```js
async function emailAlreadyExists(email) {
  const db = getFirestore();

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(
    collection(db, "emails"),
    where("email", "==", email),
    limit(1)
  ));

  return !querySnapshot.empty
}
```